# `python -m foo.bar` vs. `python foo/bar.py` for local imports

Tags: python, python-import

I'm trying to run a python file interactively. The file imports other local modules. E.g., I have `foo/bar.py` and `foo/baz.py`. I want to run `foo/bar.py` interactively, and in `foo/bar.py` I have `from foo import baz`.

From `foo`'s parent directory, I can run `python -m foo.bar`, and the import of baz works fine. But when I want to run interactively with `python -i foo/bar.py`, the import no longer works (the same is true if I do `python foo/bar.py`).

Why is that? Can I invoke python differently to get this to work? Am I organizing my code in a strange way?

Comment: `python -m foo.bar` is calling `foo.py`, and its sub module `bar`. `python -i foo/bar.py` is directly calling `bar.py`. You are calling different files.

Comment: @Sraw  that's not really what's going on.  `foo.py` doesn't even exist.

Comment: @win I have realized that I used a wrong term, maybe it should be called `package` or `lib` or something else. Anyway, that is an unit in python's module path organization.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do relative imports in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python)

Answer (score 3):

When using the `-m` option, [the current directory will be added to the start of `sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m).  In your case, that's the directory which contains `foo`.  This allows the import statement in `bar`, i.e. `from foo import baz`, to be resolved correctly.

When not using the `-m` option, [the first item in `sys.path` is the directory containing the script that was used to invoke the Python interpreter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path).  In your case, that's one dir deeper than before - it's the directory `/path/to/foo` itself.  This does not allow the import statement `from foo import baz` to be resolved correctly.

> Can I invoke python differently to get this to work?

This should work:

```
PYTHONPATH=. python foo/bar.py
```

> Am I organizing my code in a strange way?

Not really, but you'll need to get the parent directory of `foo` onto `sys.path` somehow.  The best way is to [write a `setup.py` file](https://packaging.python.org/) and then "install" your code with:

```
pip install --editable .
```

Comment: A frequent example of `-m` : `timeit`'s command-line interface i.e. `~$ python3 -m timeit 'for i in range(10): oct(i)'`.

Comment: Beware that, with any of these approaches, `bar.py` can end up being executed **twice**: once as `__main__` and once as `foo.bar`.  It’s best not to pretend that a normal module is sometimes a script; make a dedicated “module” to use with `-m`.  You can call it `__main__.py` file and then use the _package_ name with `-m`.

Comment: Assuming you're doing packaging anyway, then another option is to use the setuptools' `entry_points`/`console_scripts`.
  See [here](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation).  It's easier to get right than the `__main__.py` stuff.